can't get connection in Sqlite with capacitor
I need some help, please. I am using SQLite with the Capacitor plugin in IONIC with Angular.
It turns out that during the initial configuration of my application, I create the tables in the database. After that, I proceed to download some parameters and insert them into the tables. Once this process finishes, when I navigate to another stack in my application and try to reconnect, I get messages like: "Connection already exists."
Sometimes, I also get other messages like: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')" when using the this.db.query function, but in other components, it works fine.
It seems like I have some issues with the logic for opening the connection, and I’m not sure what to do.
This is my current code SqliteService:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CapacitorSQLite, SQLiteConnection, SQLiteDBConnection } from '@capacitor-community/sqlite';
import { Device } from '@capacitor/device';
import { Preferences } from '@capacitor/preferences';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { JsonSQLite } from 'jeep-sqlite/dist/types/interfaces/interfaces';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SqliteService {
  dbReady: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  isWeb: boolean = false;
  isIOS: boolean = false;
  dbName: string = 'sigri';
  private dbInitialized: boolean = false;
  private db: SQLiteDBConnection | undefined; // Para almacenar la conexión de la DB
  private sqlite: SQLiteConnection;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    this.dbReady = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  }

  async init() {
    console.log('Inicializando SQLite', this.dbInitialized);
    if (this.dbInitialized) return;

    const info = await Device.getInfo();
    const sqlite = CapacitorSQLite as any;

    if (info.platform == 'android') {
      try {
        await sqlite.requestPermissions();
      } catch (error) {
        alert('Permiso no concedido');
      }
    } else if (info.platform == 'web') {
      this.isWeb = true;
      await sqlite.initWebStore();
    } else if (info.platform == 'ios') {
      this.isIOS = true;
    }

    await this.setupDatabase();
    this.dbInitialized = true;
  }

  async setupDatabase() {
    const dbSetup = await Preferences.get({
      key: 'first_setup_key'
    });

    if (!dbSetup.value) {
      this.downloadDatabase();
    } else {
      this.dbName = await this.getDbName();

      await this.createConnection(this.dbName);

      this.dbReady.next(true);
    }
  }

  async createConnection(dbName: string) {
    try {
      this.sqlite = new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite);
      // Verificar si ya existe una conexión
      const existingConnection = await this.sqlite.retrieveConnection(dbName, false);
      if (existingConnection) {
        this.db = existingConnection;
        if (!this.db.isDBOpen()) {
          await this.db.open();
        }
      } else {
        this.db = await this.sqlite.createConnection(dbName, false, 'no-encryption', 1, false);
        await this.db.open();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Error creando conexión: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  }


  downloadDatabase() {
    this.api.getSubscribe('assets/db/db.json', {}).subscribe(async (jsonExport: any) => {
      const jsonstring = JSON.stringify(jsonExport);
      const isValid = await CapacitorSQLite.isJsonValid({ jsonstring });

      if (isValid.result) {
        this.dbName = jsonExport.database;

        await CapacitorSQLite.importFromJson({ jsonstring });
        await this.createConnection(this.dbName);

        await Preferences.set({ key: 'first_setup_key', value: '1' });
        await Preferences.set({ key: 'dbname', value: this.dbName });

        this.dbReady.next(true);
      } else {
        alert('JsonDatabase no es válido');
      }
    });
  }

  async getDbName() {
    if (!this.dbName) {
      const dbname = await Preferences.get({ key: 'dbname' });

      if (dbname.value) {
        this.dbName = dbname.value;
      }
    }
    return this.dbName;
  }

  // Método para obtener la conexión a la base de datos
  async getDbConnection(): Promise<SQLiteDBConnection | undefined> {
    try {
      if (!this.db?.isDBOpen()) {
        console.log('Conexión cerrada')
        await this.db?.open();
      } else {
        console.log('Conexión abierta')
      }
      return this.db;
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Error al obtener la conexión :: ' + JSON.stringify(error))
      return undefined
    }
  }
}

Then, in another service, I inject it like this:
// Get connection
const db = await this.sqliteService.getDbConnection();

// Verify country id
const selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM paises WHERE id = ?';


const result = await db.query(selectQuery, [pais.id]);

But in this other service, I run a similar query, and I get the messages mentioned earlier:
const db = await this.sqliteService.getDbConnection();

const selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM paises';

const result = await db.query(selectQuery);

this.countryJson = JSON.stringify(result)

I would really appreciate some help. I’ve reviewed a lot, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Why are you calling sqliteService in another service? and where are you calling this second service? you should only be doing the init in the app.component.ts file and only 1 time.
